# How Can I Overwrite a List Variable Using Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

If I want to queue a build using AzureDevops with overwritten variables, I have to pass a parameters string:

```
{   "definition" : { "id" : [BUILD_ID] },
    "parameters" : str(variables_to_overwrite) 
}
```

where variables_to_overwrite is a dictionary like so:

```
variables_to_overwrite = {
       "list_1" : str( ['A', 'B', 'C'] )
       "list_2" : str( ['D', 'E'] )
    }
```

**If I don't cast these lists as strings, the build will not queue.** I print out params before queuing the build and they look correct:

```
{'definition': {'id': [BUILD_ID}, 
 'parameters': '{\'list_1\': "\'[\'A\', \'B\', \'C\']\'", \'list_2\': "\'[\'D\', \'E\']\'}'
```

but when I have the build print out the arguments it sees, it prints:

```
'--list_1', "'['A", "B',", "'C"]'", '--list_2', "'['D", "E']'"
```

**As you can see, the single and double quotes have become quite mixed up**, which means programs that parse args don't see this as two args, but seven!

I tried force-replacing all the double quotes with single quotes, but when I do that, the build won't queue. I even tried rewriting it like so:

```
{'definition': {'id': [BUILD_ID}, 
 'parameters': '{\'list_1\': \'[\'A\', \'B\', \'C\']\', \'list_2\': \'[\'D\', \'E\']\'}'
```

But when I get back the build result, it has done the same thing of adding in double-quotes mixed up with single quotes (in exactly the same way as previously described).

**How can I prevent DevOps from destroying the quote pairing in things like lists and dicts that are passed as parameters?** I have tried every permutation I can think of, including manually wrapping it in quotes, replacing quotes, using json.dumps, etc. Nothing works. The only way to get the build to queue is to pass a string, and no matter what quote inputs it gets, whether escaped or not, devOps goes through and replaces all quotes with a `single-quote, double-quote` pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lengthy trial and error, I determined that Azure DevOps requires that lists intended for overwriting have this format:

```
'[]',
'"[\'A\', \'B\']"'
```

That is to say, `single-quote, double-quote, bracket, escaped single quotes inside the list, bracket, double-quote, single-quote`. Quote styles cannot be interchanged and the escape character is required. Any deviation will result in the problem described in the question.

This is pretty much impossible to do in Python using `str()`. However, it can be done using `repr()`.

When defining `variables_to_overwrite`, do not cast any lists to string (as the question shows). Instead, leave them as lists and then perform the following sort of replacement:

```
if variables_to_overwrite:
    for key in variables_to_overwrite:
        value = variables_to_overwrite[key]
        if type(value) == list:
            variables_to_overwrite[key] = '"' + repr(value) + '"'   # THIS FORMAT IS CRUCIAL
```

Finally, define your parameters:

```
params = {
    "definition": {
        "id": build_id
    },
    "parameters" : str(variables_to_overwrite)   # THIS IS THE ONLY PLACE TO USE STR()
}
```

This will convert the list into the weird string format Azure DevOps requires and prevent DevOps from mangling the quotes.